# Basic Communication between two fragments and set id for fragment on class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have one activity - MainActivity. Within this Activity, I have two fragments, both of which I created declaratively within the XML.

I am trying to pass the String of text input by the user into Fragment A to the text view in Fragment B. However this is proving to be very difficult. Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

I am aware that a fragment can get a reference to its activity using `getActivity()`. So I'm guessing I would start there?
How can I set an id for the fragment in the adapter

I use a library for slider:
https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper

Comment: there are many ways to go about this. the Android docs are a good place to start: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: Are you showing both fragment at a time?

Comment: no but first fragment data affects on the second fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Fragment#setTargetFragment`  and `Fragment#getTargetFragment`
check out the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment())

In your MainActivity you can do:

```
fragment1.setTargetFragment(fragment2)
```

and in fragment1 you can use typeCast

```
class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private void passInput(String string) {
        ((Fragment2) getTargetFragment())
            .updateTextView(string);
    }

}
```

For more complex data handling, with multiple fragments, you should use the MVVM pattern, where a viewModel is registered with the activity lifecycle, and each fragment can communicate with that instance and observe data changes.

Comment: because i use special adapter for this library and not extend fragmentActvity

Comment: ok, checkout the MVVM pattern, once you understand it, it will surely help you. good luck

Answer (score 0):

to make a communication between two fragments, its better to use a communicator interface
1- make your activity implements an interface with methods that change data
2- pass that interface to your fragments

you may find this link helpful https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: i reading this but can't id to my fragments because i use special adapter for this library and not extend fragmentActvity

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to pass the String of text input by the user into Fragment
>   A to the text view in Fragment B. However this is proving to be very
>   difficult. Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

You can achieve this easily with [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

In Fragment A

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(text));

public static class MessageEvent {
    String text;

    public MessageEvent(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

In Fragment B

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(FragmentA.MessageEvent event) {
Log.d(“akshay”,”text= ”+event.text)
   }
```